# Is there any test-suite able to automatically choose a bunch of types and values that match the constraints?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing

In my journey to learn Haskell I'm re-implementing a lot of functions that already exist. I get my code to compile (which means that types check), but I'm not sure whether the behavior is correct.

###### QuickCheck and its limitation

I've been testing some simple functions with QuickCheck and that works well. However it feels limited with functions that are a bit more complex. For instance let's say that I re-implement `liftA2`. (This is just one random example. Forget that it's a method. Take any other function you like.)

```hs
-- my re-implementation of liftA2
liftA2' :: Applicative app => (a -> b -> c) -> app a -> app b -> app c
liftA2' f aa ab = f <$> aa <*> ab
```

I'd like to test whether it behaves exactly like `liftA2` for some (ideally any) function `f` and `Applicative` instance `app`.

Doing this with QuickCheck requires choosing one function and one instance. Then I have to write a line similar to this:

```hs
-- test whether liftA2' behaves exactly like liftA2
-- ...only for the (,) function and [Int] instances :(
quickCheck $ \aa bb -> liftA2 (,) aa bb === liftA2' (,) (aa :: [Int]) (bb :: [Int])
```

But this feels pretty far from ideal: the thing I just wrote is more convoluted than the function itself and it tests my `lift2A'` against only one function (`,`) and only one type (`[Int]`).

###### What I'm looking for

I would love it if it were possible to write something like...

```hs
-- test whether liftA2' behaves exactly like liftA2
check $ liftA2 === liftA2'
```

and then let the test suite choose a bunch of types, functions and values to run some tests: ideally it should test various corner cases and reach 100% coverage (or warn me if it couldn't cover everything).

I believe that something like a GHC plugin should be able to do this, since it could see the type and the constraints of everything involved. But a module like QuickCheck can not.

###### Question:

Is there any testing suite for Haskell that is able to come up with types and values that match the types and type constraints?

Answer (score 4):

QuickCheck doesn't limit you to testing against only one function. Here's how you could test against arbitrary functions instead:

```
quickCheck $ \(Fn2 f) aa bb -> liftA2 f aa bb === liftA2' (f :: Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)) (aa :: [Int]) (bb :: [Int])
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to get what you want for types too, although you can probably mitigate a lot of it by keeping parametricity in mind when you're choosing your types. For example, this would be a step in the right direction:

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Poly

quickCheck $ \(Fn2 f) aa bb -> liftA2 f aa bb === liftA2' (f :: A -> B -> C) (aa :: [A]) (bb :: [B])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Fn2, A, B etc. This is a big improvement already. I'm upvoting, but not accepting the answer yet though, because I'm still hoping to find something that picks arbitrary typeclasses and doesn't require me to hint what types are required (in theory whatever compiles/interprets my file should already have that information).